# how to update columns in one application databse to another application database column using rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am new to rails. using mysql database, 
i have 2 rails application, that 2 applications running same time with different ports numbers. 
Eexample one app in localhost:3000 another app in localhost:4000..
in 2 applications i have different database name, and different tables.
take 1st application it contains notedb databse, notebooks table, in notebooks table it contains cost column.
2 application contains textbooks table, in textbooks table it contains also cost column.
My question is, in 1st application when i add or update cost column it save in first application cost column and also 2nd application cost column.
please help me i am new to ruby on rails. i am using rails 4.2.6, please give complete reference. 
i am new ruby and ruby on rails, please write some code or give me the code link..

```
1st app database.yml

default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: root
password: mypassword
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

development:
     <<: *default
     database: notebookdb

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
  # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
  # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
  test:
    <<: *default
    database: notebookdb

```
2nd app database.yml

default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: root
password: mypassword
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

development:
    <<: *default
    database: textbookdb

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
  #  re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
  # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
  test:
    <<: *default
    database: textbookdb

Comment: Please share your database.yml for both applications

Comment: 1st app database.yml

default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: root
password: mypassword
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock   2nd app database.yml

default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: root
password: mypassword
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write API request call from your one application to another application and update column.

Comment: i am new to rails i dont know API request call

Comment: You try with Httpparty gem?